# How to change background of textview in pygobject "gtk3"?

Tags: python, gtk3, pygobject

i am writing a text editor in gtk 3 using python.
in gtk 2 i used to do
`self.modify_base(Gtk.StateType.NORMAL, Gtk.gdk.Color(bg))`
in PyGObject i think it has to do something with style context but i am not sure what is the right way, i found only this documentation on the web, but it is not enough:
[python gtk3 tutorial](http://readthedocs.org/docs/python-gtk-3-tutorial/en/latest/introduction.html)
i thought this code maybe the beginning of it:

```
    context = self.get_style_context()
    context.set_background(Gtk.STYLE_PROPERTY_BACKGROUND_COLOR)
```

so any ideas ?

Comment: GtkTextView is a complex widget, and no you won't change background color of the text inside the widget with that.
Now, that's the best documentation, and as a complement you should look into C docs for Gtk since those applies as well.
To the point, for changing the background of the text, try changing the properties of the text. How: add 2 GtkTextMark, one at the beginning, and other at the end of text, and change the background color property of that text.
Check gtk3-demo program for directions, that one it's in C though.

Comment: Here's an example of styling a GtkTextView using GTK3 with CSS. It's C code though but it should help you.
[http://www.gtkforums.com/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=988&p=195276&hilit=Styling+a+GtkTextView+with+Gtk3+and+Css#p195276](http://www.gtkforums.com/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=988&p=195276&hilit=Styling%20a%20GtkTextView%20with%20Gtk3%20and%20Css#p195276)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i found the answer, first thing you gotta import Gdk.

```
from gi.repository import Gdk
```

supposing that Gtk.TextView instance is called doc

```
doc.override_background_color(Gtk.StateFlags.NORMAL, Gdk.RGBA(0, 0, 0, 1))
```

change the Gdk.RGBA(0, 0, 0, 1) as you wish

rgba, each value lies between 0.0 and 0.1, r stands for red, g for green, b for blue and a stands for alpha.